# How can we achieve dynamic items with dynamic content in custom table cell?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

How can I achieve the dynamic no of items with dynamic content size one after other and in next line if the content gets more than superview in a custom table view cell?

Please refer image for question clarification.

[image]

Comment: Uncleared question.

Answer (score 0):

The question you posted is a bit long and actually requests for multiple things since you didn't post what you have tried and what part you are having trouble with. There are many ways of doing this so let's start with normal label:

An `UILabel` can have attributed string under `attributedText` which can be used to achieve the visual design you are showing in your image. To lay them out horizontally we could use `sizeToFit` to get their width. Assume something like:

```
func layoutLabels(_ labels: [UILabel], inView view: UIView, horizontalSeparator: CGFloat = 4.0) {
    var x: CGFloat = 0.0
    labels.forEach { label in
        label.sizeToFit() // Will make it's size just right
        label.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0.0, width: label.frame.width, height: label.frame.height)
        x = label.frame.maxX + horizontalSeparator
        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Now to add vertical part we simply need to add maximum width and also add `y` component:

```
func layoutLabels(_ labels: [UILabel], inView view: UIView, maximumWidth: CGFloat, lineHeight: CGFloat, horizontalSeparator: CGFloat = 4.0, verticalSeparator: CGFloat = 2.0) {
    var x: CGFloat = 0.0
    var y: CGFloat = 0.0
    labels.forEach { label in
        label.sizeToFit() // Will make it's size just right
        var newX = x + label.frame.width

        if newX > maximumWidth {
            if x == 0.0 {
                // We are at the beginning of the line and a single label is simply too large. We will need to reduce it's width
                label.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: maximumWidth, height: label.frame.height)
            } else {
                // We should go into new line
                x = 0.0
                y += lineHeight
                label.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: min(label.frame.width, maximumWidth), height: label.frame.height)
                newX = x + label.frame.width
            }
        } else {
            label.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: min(label.frame.width, maximumWidth), height: label.frame.height)
        }

        x = newX + horizontalSeparator
        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

This should now let you fill labels the way as on your image. We are also checking for line breaks and labels that can not fit overall width of your view. So now we need to define what is the actual size of your view. `y` should return that but we need to be able to use it in a table view cell. So we can simply return it:

```
func layoutLabels(_ labels: [UILabel], inView view: UIView, maximumWidth: CGFloat, lineHeight: CGFloat, horizontalSeparator: CGFloat = 4.0, verticalSeparator: CGFloat = 2.0) -> CGFloat {
    ...
    return labels.count > 0 ? y + lineHeight : 0.0
}
```

Now in your table view cell it might be best to use some constraint outlet:

```
protocol Tag {
    func createLabel() -> UILabel
}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private var tagsPanel: UIView!
    @IBOutlet private var tagsPanelHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var tags: [Tag]!

    func refresh() {
        tagsPanel.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() } // Ugly, needs improvement
        let height = layoutLabels(tags.map { $0.createLabel() }, inView: tagsPanel, maximumWidth: tagsPanel.frame.width, lineHeight: 40.0)
        tagsPanelHeightConstraint?.constant = height
    }

}
```

Now the problem is that your table view needs to refresh because your table view cell might have resized. You will need to have a reference to your table view and simple call begin/end updates on it.

```
var tags: [Tag]!

weak var tableView: UITableView? // Assigned in cellForRowAtIndexPath

func refresh() {
    tagsPanel.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() } // Ugly, needs improvement
    let height = layoutLabels(tags.map { $0.createLabel() }, inView: tagsPanel, maximumWidth: tagsPanel.frame.width, lineHeight: 40.0)
    if let tagsPanelHeightConstraint = tagsPanelHeightConstraint, tagsPanelHeightConstraint.constant != height {
        tagsPanelHeightConstraint.constant = height
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        tableView?.endUpdates()
    }

}
```

Good luck.